# I have 60 Million product in my Magento 2 but indexer:redindex not working

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, indexing

I have 60 Millions products in my Magento 2 Store.
But when i run bin/magento indexer:reindex command.
It is struck on Category Product Index.
[image]
When i check on backend it is stuck here.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]
How to solve this error.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Btw how many effective SKUs do you have: products * customer groups * websites? select count(*) from catalog_product_index_price? Is it Magento CE or EE? Do you have installed Inventory?

Comment: @transversus Thanks for your response how to check how many products are effective means how much more time it will take to complete is there a way to check this ?

Comment: Indexation time depends on number of effective skus (eSKUs). Websites and customer groups are multipliers for products. If you have 60 million products, but for example 10 customer groups and 10 websites, then real eSKUs are 60 millions * 10 * 10 = 6 billion. With 6 billion eSKUs it will take much longer than with 60 million products with 1 website and 1 customer group. Besides, what Magento editions do you have: open source or commerce? Do you have Inventory Management installed?

Comment: Thanks for your response
I have 60 million product 4 customer groups and 1 website
Magento Open source and version = 2.3.5-p1.
Do you give any idea about time it will really helpfull
what's this Do you have Inventory Management installed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess with such amount of products it can take couple of hours for category product index to complete.

If your indexer is stuck in some status you can invalidate the status of your Category Products indexer by running `bin/magento indexer:reset catalog_category_product` command.

Magento does not recommend to keep your indexers in `Update on Save` mode, especially if you have about 60 million products. Please, set your indexers to `Update by Schedule` mode and run your indexers by cron or manually by `bin/magento indexer:reindex` command: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/index-management.html#best-practices-for-reindexing

If you want to check for sure if indexation is still running or not, you can run `show processlist` command in your database. If there is only 1 process and it's show processlist, then indexation is most likely not running, and you can invalidate your stuck in processing indexer by `bin/magento indexer:reset` command: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html